# Instancing python output

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

[image]I've managed to make a random name generator in python that output the result in a geometry node. But now i was wondering how can i generate multiple strings thanks to that script and instance them on points on my scene ?
Right now when i plug the string node in a instancing node, it instances the letters separately.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information, like your scripts and screenshots?

Comment: my bad, i've just uploaded a screenshot of the whole setup

Answer (score 1):

i know - it is not a nice way, but until now GN cannot handle string arrays or arrays at all - but this tedious workaround works:

[image]